# MVC3 how to get innerHtml from the return sting of @Html.ValidationMessageFor<> method?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, validation

I want to show the validation message summary in the tool tip of an html box. Something like this,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Contract.PrimaryContact.FirstName, new { @class = "quarter", title = @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Contract.PrimaryContact.FirstName) })
```

How can I do it? As of now am seeing the entire html mark up of the validation message in the title. Is there a way I can just see the validation message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the only proper way is to reimplement the Validation helper methods. Fortunately it isn't hard and the source is available online.

Comment: May you please guide me to a suitable example? I tried looking for it before posting the question. Might be my search keywords were wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The source is available here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1ccfcdfc11da#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fHtml%2fValidationExtensions.cs